# Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined. dependency is installed

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have used port 27017 for a different project. The terminal with the port is up and running, and I can connect it to robo 3t to prove it.

When i open another terminal and run mongoDB, it also works. I have it installed as a dependency and is in my package.json file showing the version.

When I use the code below to connect to mongoDB I am getting the errors that follow. It seems that mongoDB wasn't installed, but I do not understand how that can be.

Any ideas as to why this won't work? Thanks.

my code:

```
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/HEALTH', (err, client) => {
 if (err) {
 return console.log('Unable to connect to MongoDB server');
 }
  console.log('Connected to MongoDB server');

 client.close();
  });
```

the error BASH is giving me:

```
 $ node server/server.js
    C:\Users\shail\Desktop\HEALTH\server\server.js:3
   MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/HEALTH', (err, client) => {
        ^

   TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take out the { } from ‘MongoClient’, so the code will be like:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
```